# Copy part of 3-d array to 2-d array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, copy

Let's say I have a multidimensional array:

```
var arr = new double[2, 5, 5]
{
    {
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
    },
    {
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 2, 2, 2, 1 },
        { 1, 2, 2, 2, 1 },
        { 1, 2, 2, 2, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
    },
};
```

I want to copy 3 by 3 part of that array starting from index **[1,1,1]** till index **[1,3,3]** (all 2 values).

What is the most efficient way of doing so ? So far, I do it with a loop:

```
var arr2 = new int[3, 3];

int x_start = 1;
int y_start = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < arr2.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < arr2.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        arr2[i, j] = arr[1, x_start + i, y_start + j];
    }
}
```

But I wonder if there is a more efficient way of doing it ?

Comment: That’s the most efficient way to do it. You are using fast loops and only loop over those indexes you are interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[poke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216074/poke) already made the same point in their comment, but this is essentially the best way of doing this.

> That’s the most efficient way to do it. You are using fast loops and only loop over those indexes you are interested in. - [poke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216074/poke)

You could possibly cache the two GetLength() calls in an integer, but I doubt that'd make any meaningful difference in performance.